# Stuffing multiple rows to see if columns are populated?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to figure out a way in MySql to stuff multiple records for the same user into a single row to see which columns are populated. For example:

```
Username       Height       Weight       Age  
Bob123          6ft
Bob123                      100lbs   
Bob123                      120lbs       25yrs
```

Let's say I have these three records in a table. I want to be able to combine them into a single row that just indicates if each column was populated in **any** of the records. My hopeful result record would look something like this for each user:

```
Username       Height      Weight        Age  
Bob123         True        True          True
```

Is there a way to do this in MySQL or do I need to look at doing this programmatically?

Comment: do your rows have blank values?

Comment: Everything is set to null if unpopulated

Answer (score 1):

A generic sql method would be like this:

```
select username
, case when maxheight is not null then 'true' else 'false' end hasheight
, etc
from 
(select username
, max(height) maxheight
, etc
from yourtables
where whatever
group by username) temp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE person (Username VARCHAR(55),       Height VARCHAR(55),       Weight VARCHAR(55) ,      Age VARCHAR(55)  
);
INSERT INTO person VALUES
('Bob123'   ,       '6ft'   ,       NULL       ,      NULL),
('Bob123'   ,       NULL      ,      '100lbs'   ,     NULL),
('Bob123'   ,       NULL      ,      '120lbs'   ,    '25yrs');


SELECT username,
    CASE height WHEN NULL THEN ' ' ELSE 'True'  END, 
    CASE weight WHEN NULL THEN ' ' ELSE 'True'  END,
    CASE age WHEN NULL THEN ' ' ELSE 'True'  END
FROM person
GROUP BY username;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bced0/1)